# How to get correct systemBars height using compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I know this seems trivial but I've looked up every doc, maybe I'm missing something.
I am trying to get this

[image: display]

across different device screen size (focusing on compact types). I successfully got screen height using `LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp`

Now I'm implementing edge-to-edge display.
I followed this [doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge), but i get this

[image: display2]

looking at this there is a space between them (blue), because of the feature to draw behind systembars. then i tried to get the systemBars height(top & bottom) to add to the boxes resp to compensate for the extra space.
I used `inset.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())` which returns the heights of the systembars but after that the boxes overlap(yellow)

[image: display3]

I logged the values I'm getting from the `insets`, it was quite more than the values of `LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDP`

**How do i compensate for the space or get the correct height for the systemBars?**

Here is my code :

```
@Composable
fun MyBox() {

val view = LocalView.current
val inset = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)!!

val insetSystemBar = inset.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()) //Insets{left=0, top=136, right=0, bottom=132}
val insetStatusBar = insetSystemBar.top // 136
val insetNavBar = insetSystemBar.bottom  // 132

val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp //This returns 753

val testHeightRatio = 0.5
val TopBoxHeight = (((screenHeight * testHeightRatio).roundToInt())).dp   // 377
val BottomBoxHeight = (((screenHeight * testHeightRatio).roundToInt())).dp   // 377

val TopBoxAndStatusBarHeight = TopBoxHeight + insetStatusBar.dp   // 513
val BottomBoxAndNavBar = BottomBoxHeight + insetNavBar.dp    // 509

MyBoxTheme {
    Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xFF00B8D4))
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(BottomBoxAndNavBar)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .background(Color(0x86FF0303)),
            )

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(TopBoxAndStatusBarHeight)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color(0x8FFFDD03))
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            )
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply do `fillMaxHeight(fraction = 0.5f)` on both boxes? Or put the boxes in column and give them same `.weight()`?

Comment: This actually solved the my problem, what an oversight...thank you very much